# three js + TrackballControls + rotation. Не получается повернуть по осям X и Z

Tags: typescript, angular, three.js

прикрутил ThreeJS к Angular8 (на вопрос не влияет, просто используется TS + JS).

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols';
```

есть 3х график с несколькими объектами который отлично управляется мышью,
НО требуется также задать управление вращением с кнопок <,>,Up,Down,Reset ...

кода много, не хочу захламлять задачу.

проблема: требуется кнопками Up, Down задать соответствующее вращение на 1 шаг вокруг центра координат (центра сцены). Не могу повернуть (полностью на 360) сцену либо камеру вокруг сцены вокруг осей X и Z так чтобы возвращаться в исходную точку в любом направлении двигаясь строго вертикально.

Вращение вокруг оси Y (горизонтальное) решил формулами:

```
const theta = 0.1;

const x = this.camera.position.x;
const z = this.camera.position.z;

this.camera.position.x = x * Math.cos(theta) + z * Math.sin(theta);
this.camera.position.z = z * Math.cos(theta) - x * Math.sin(theta);
this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);
```

конкретно что нужно (ИЛИ):

1. аналогичные тригонометрические формулы для вращения вокруг осей X и Z

   (такое решение не работает)

   ```
   const theta = 0.1;

   const y = this.camera.position.y;
   const z = this.camera.position.z;

   this.camera.position.y = y * Math.cos(theta) + z * Math.sin(theta);
   this.camera.position.z = z * Math.cos(theta) - y * Math.sin(theta);
   ```
2. действительно работающий метод, вращающий сцену или камеру по осям X и Z

Comment: хочу если это создаст нужный эффект. Что Вы имеете ввиду? Какие методы?

Comment: я сделаю вечерком пример

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: простите, вчера не успел =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, вроде все работает как надо, строчки которые я изменил в `TrackballControls` я пометил комментом `/// MODIFIED`

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, innerWidth/innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 5;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

let controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.position.x=-1;
scene.add( cube );

var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32);
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( spheregeometry, material );
sphere.position.x=1;
scene.add( sphere );

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(500, 100, 0x666666, 0x444444));

function render() {
    controls.update();
    cube.rotation.x+=0.01;
    cube.rotation.y+=0.01;
    cube.rotation.z+=0.02;
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

render();

function horizontal(v){
    controls._movePrev.copy( controls.getMouseOnCircle( 0, 0 ) );
    controls._moveCurr.copy( controls.getMouseOnCircle( v*10, 0 ) );
    controls.update();
}

function vertical(v){
    controls._movePrev.copy( controls.getMouseOnCircle( 0, 0 ) );
    controls._moveCurr.copy( controls.getMouseOnCircle( 0, v*10 ) );
    controls.update();
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; overflow:hidden}
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/107/three.min.js"></script>
<script>
/**
 * @author Eberhard Graether / http://egraether.com/
 * @author Mark Lundin  / http://mark-lundin.com
 * @author Simone Manini / http://daron1337.github.io
 * @author Luca Antiga  / http://lantiga.github.io
 */

THREE.TrackballControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

 var _this = this;
 var STATE = { NONE: - 1, ROTATE: 0, ZOOM: 1, PAN: 2, TOUCH_ROTATE: 3, TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN: 4 };

 this.object = object;
 this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;

 // API

 this.enabled = true;

 this.screen = { left: 0, top: 0, width: 0, height: 0 };

 this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
 this.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
 this.panSpeed = 0.3;

 this.noRotate = false;
 this.noZoom = false;
 this.noPan = false;

 this.staticMoving = false;
 this.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.2;

 this.minDistance = 0;
 this.maxDistance = Infinity;

 this.keys = [ 65 /*A*/, 83 /*S*/, 68 /*D*/ ];

 this.mouseButtons = { LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE, MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.ZOOM, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN };

 // internals

 this.target = new THREE.Vector3();

 var EPS = 0.000001;

 var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

 var _state = STATE.NONE,
  _keyState = STATE.NONE,

  _eye = new THREE.Vector3(),

  _movePrev = this._movePrev = new THREE.Vector2(),   /// MODIFIED
  _moveCurr = this._moveCurr = new THREE.Vector2(),   /// MODIFIED

  _lastAxis = new THREE.Vector3(),
  _lastAngle = 0,

  _zoomStart = new THREE.Vector2(),
  _zoomEnd = new THREE.Vector2(),

  _touchZoomDistanceStart = 0,
  _touchZoomDistanceEnd = 0,

  _panStart = new THREE.Vector2(),
  _panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();

 // for reset

 this.target0 = this.target.clone();
 this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
 this.up0 = this.object.up.clone();

 // events

 var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };
 var startEvent = { type: 'start' };
 var endEvent = { type: 'end' };


 // methods

 this.handleResize = function () {

  if ( this.domElement === document ) {

   this.screen.left = 0;
   this.screen.top = 0;
   this.screen.width = window.innerWidth;
   this.screen.height = window.innerHeight;

  } else {

   var box = this.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
   // adjustments come from similar code in the jquery offset() function
   var d = this.domElement.ownerDocument.documentElement;
   this.screen.left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - d.clientLeft;
   this.screen.top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - d.clientTop;
   this.screen.width = box.width;
   this.screen.height = box.height;

  }

 };

 var getMouseOnScreen = ( function () {

  var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

  return function getMouseOnScreen( pageX, pageY ) {

   vector.set(
    ( pageX - _this.screen.left ) / _this.screen.width,
    ( pageY - _this.screen.top ) / _this.screen.height
   );

   return vector;

  };

 }() );

  
 var getMouseOnCircle = this.getMouseOnCircle= ( function () {  /// MODIFIED

  var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

  return function getMouseOnCircle( pageX, pageY ) {

   vector.set(
    ( ( pageX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left ) / ( _this.screen.width * 0.5 ) ),
    ( ( _this.screen.height + 2 * ( _this.screen.top - pageY ) ) / _this.screen.width ) // screen.width intentional
   );

   return vector;

  };

 }() );

 this.rotateCamera = ( function () {

  var axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
   quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(),
   eyeDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   objectUpDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   objectSidewaysDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   moveDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
   angle;

  return function rotateCamera() {

   moveDirection.set( _moveCurr.x - _movePrev.x, _moveCurr.y - _movePrev.y, 0 );
   angle = moveDirection.length();

   if ( angle ) {

    _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );

    eyeDirection.copy( _eye ).normalize();
    objectUpDirection.copy( _this.object.up ).normalize();
    objectSidewaysDirection.crossVectors( objectUpDirection, eyeDirection ).normalize();

    objectUpDirection.setLength( _moveCurr.y - _movePrev.y );
    objectSidewaysDirection.setLength( _moveCurr.x - _movePrev.x );

    moveDirection.copy( objectUpDirection.add( objectSidewaysDirection ) );

    axis.crossVectors( moveDirection, _eye ).normalize();

    angle *= _this.rotateSpeed;
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle );

    _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
    _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    _lastAxis.copy( axis );
    _lastAngle = angle;

   } else if ( ! _this.staticMoving && _lastAngle ) {

    _lastAngle *= Math.sqrt( 1.0 - _this.dynamicDampingFactor );
    _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( _lastAxis, _lastAngle );
    _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
    _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

   }

   _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );

  };

 }() );


 this.zoomCamera = function () {

  var factor;

  if ( _state === STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN ) {

   factor = _touchZoomDistanceStart / _touchZoomDistanceEnd;
   _touchZoomDistanceStart = _touchZoomDistanceEnd;
   _eye.multiplyScalar( factor );

  } else {

   factor = 1.0 + ( _zoomEnd.y - _zoomStart.y ) * _this.zoomSpeed;

   if ( factor !== 1.0 && factor > 0.0 ) {

    _eye.multiplyScalar( factor );

   }

   if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

    _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

   } else {

    _zoomStart.y += ( _zoomEnd.y - _zoomStart.y ) * this.dynamicDampingFactor;

   }

  }

 };

 this.panCamera = ( function () {

  var mouseChange = new THREE.Vector2(),
   objectUp = new THREE.Vector3(),
   pan = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function panCamera() {

   mouseChange.copy( _panEnd ).sub( _panStart );

   if ( mouseChange.lengthSq() ) {

    mouseChange.multiplyScalar( _eye.length() * _this.panSpeed );

    pan.copy( _eye ).cross( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.x );
    pan.add( objectUp.copy( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.y ) );

    _this.object.position.add( pan );
    _this.target.add( pan );

    if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

     _panStart.copy( _panEnd );

    } else {

     _panStart.add( mouseChange.subVectors( _panEnd, _panStart ).multiplyScalar( _this.dynamicDampingFactor ) );

    }

   }

  };

 }() );

 this.checkDistances = function () {

  if ( ! _this.noZoom || ! _this.noPan ) {

   if ( _eye.lengthSq() > _this.maxDistance * _this.maxDistance ) {

    _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye.setLength( _this.maxDistance ) );
    _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

   }

   if ( _eye.lengthSq() < _this.minDistance * _this.minDistance ) {

    _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye.setLength( _this.minDistance ) );
    _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

   }

  }

 };

 this.update = function () {

  _eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );

  if ( ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _this.rotateCamera();

  }

  if ( ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _this.zoomCamera();

  }

  if ( ! _this.noPan ) {

   _this.panCamera();

  }

  _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye );

  _this.checkDistances();

  _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

  if ( lastPosition.distanceToSquared( _this.object.position ) > EPS ) {

   _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

   lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );

  }

 };

 this.reset = function () {

  _state = STATE.NONE;
  _keyState = STATE.NONE;

  _this.target.copy( _this.target0 );
  _this.object.position.copy( _this.position0 );
  _this.object.up.copy( _this.up0 );

  _eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );

  _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

  _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

  lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );

 };

 // listeners

 function keydown( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', keydown );

  if ( _keyState !== STATE.NONE ) {

   return;

  } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.ROTATE ] && ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _keyState = STATE.ROTATE;

  } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.ZOOM ] && ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _keyState = STATE.ZOOM;

  } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.PAN ] && ! _this.noPan ) {

   _keyState = STATE.PAN;

  }

 }

 function keyup() {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  _keyState = STATE.NONE;

  window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );

 }

 function mousedown( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  if ( _state === STATE.NONE ) {

   switch ( event.button ) {

    case _this.mouseButtons.LEFT:
     _state = STATE.ROTATE;
     break;

    case _this.mouseButtons.MIDDLE:
     _state = STATE.ZOOM;
     break;

    case _this.mouseButtons.RIGHT:
     _state = STATE.PAN;
     break;

    default:
     _state = STATE.NONE;

   }

  }

  var state = ( _keyState !== STATE.NONE ) ? _keyState : _state;

  if ( state === STATE.ROTATE && ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
   _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );

  } else if ( state === STATE.ZOOM && ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _zoomStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
   _zoomEnd.copy( _zoomStart );

  } else if ( state === STATE.PAN && ! _this.noPan ) {

   _panStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
   _panEnd.copy( _panStart );

  }

  document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
  document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );

  _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

 }

 function mousemove( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  var state = ( _keyState !== STATE.NONE ) ? _keyState : _state;

  if ( state === STATE.ROTATE && ! _this.noRotate ) {

   _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
   _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

  } else if ( state === STATE.ZOOM && ! _this.noZoom ) {

   _zoomEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

  } else if ( state === STATE.PAN && ! _this.noPan ) {

   _panEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

  }

 }

 function mouseup( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  _state = STATE.NONE;

  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup );
  _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function mousewheel( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  if ( _this.noZoom === true ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  switch ( event.deltaMode ) {

   case 2:
    // Zoom in pages
    _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.025;
    break;

   case 1:
    // Zoom in lines
    _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.01;
    break;

   default:
    // undefined, 0, assume pixels
    _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.00025;
    break;

  }

  _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );
  _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function touchstart( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 1:
    _state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
    _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
    _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
    break;

   default: // 2 or more
    _state = STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN;
    var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
    var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
    _touchZoomDistanceEnd = _touchZoomDistanceStart = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

    var x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX + event.touches[ 1 ].pageX ) / 2;
    var y = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageY + event.touches[ 1 ].pageY ) / 2;
    _panStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( x, y ) );
    _panEnd.copy( _panStart );
    break;

  }

  _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

 }

 function touchmove( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 1:
    _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
    _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
    break;

   default: // 2 or more
    var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
    var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
    _touchZoomDistanceEnd = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

    var x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX + event.touches[ 1 ].pageX ) / 2;
    var y = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageY + event.touches[ 1 ].pageY ) / 2;
    _panEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( x, y ) );
    break;

  }

 }

 function touchend( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 0:
    _state = STATE.NONE;
    break;

   case 1:
    _state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
    _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
    _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
    break;

  }

  _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function contextmenu( event ) {

  if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();

 }

 this.dispose = function () {

  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', mousedown, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'wheel', mousewheel, false );

  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
  this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );

  window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
  window.removeEventListener( 'keyup', keyup, false );

 };

 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', mousedown, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'wheel', mousewheel, false );

 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
 this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

 window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
 window.addEventListener( 'keyup', keyup, false );

 this.handleResize();

 // force an update at start
 this.update();

};

THREE.TrackballControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
THREE.TrackballControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.TrackballControls;


</script>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin:5px;">
<button onclick="horizontal(1)"><</button>
<button onclick="horizontal(-1)">></button>
<button onclick="vertical(1)">v</button>
<button onclick="vertical(-1)">^</button>
</div>
```

Comment: согласен, если смотреть с 0 проекцией то вращение действительно происходит вертикально. Но ведь нет ни единого 3Д графика без аксонометрии, всегда стараются показать оси со смещением.

Попробуйте сместить вправо или влево камеру и затем выполнить вертикальное перемещение. Вот также и у меня выходит вращение по "воронке" во всех найденных мной способах. А нужно строго вертикально даже если было до этого горизонтальное смещение (ведь оно есть всегда на подобных графиках)

Comment: @xalex а Вы OrbitControls пробовали?

Comment: >а Вы OrbitControls пробовали?
да, trackballcontrols (мне так показалось) с мышью лучше работает
на приведенные выше формулы не влияет                                                                                          

>приходит на ум то что надо точку обзора сместить обратно в центр, повернуть и потом обратно сместить
если мы точку обзора берем за константу в 3д координатах(xyz) то и вернемся в нее же. Цель вычислить новую точку (новые xyz).

Comment: @xalex смотрите изменения

Comment: очень круто! Спасибо!
Поведение именно то что нужно, жаль что Вам пришлось "в недра" углубиться.
Теперь буду думать как это в ReadMe "оформить"

Comment: @xalex ну это всего один файл и он не из либы а отдельно, так что не вижу проблем особых